# Padding not displaying properly

Tags: html, css

I'm testing out my CSS at http://flexibletheme.tumblr.com/ and trying to make the website responsive to a small screen size.

Only problem is, I can't get the padding to work on *aside* element. To reproduce the problem resize your browser window till the sidebar stops floating to the right (this will appear at the bottom, once the screen size is below width of 600px.

All the CSS is inline for now, to view the css. Part relevant to the resizing starts at:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
```

Edit: This image shows the padding in purple (via Firebug) not displaying properly:
[image: padding not displaying]

Comment: In what way is the padding’s display not proper? How do you expect the padding to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the padding isn’t working? Chrome’s web inspector seems to confirm that the padding is there as declared.

I do notice that your `<aside>` element ends up positioned outside the left edge of your layout, but that’s because it’s floated right and has `width: 100%;` assigned to it.

Comment: Shouldn't the padding push the next inwards, right now the text is being cut off and the padding is outside the box (see purple line).

Comment: I get what you're trying to say now. To resolve the issue, the width should be `width: 95%;` to compensate for the padding which is 5% on the `<aside>` element.

Comment: Yup, that’s the stuff: `width` means the width of the element’s content area. Padding, borders and margin are outside of the content area. ([The `box-sizing` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing) allows you to change that, but IE 7 and 6 don’t support it.) You’ll actually need the width to be 90% though, as `padding: 5%;` means 5% padding on the left side, and another 5% on the right.

Answer (score 0):

from reading your code in Chrome's Inspector, I can see that the following rule is applied when you minimize the screen

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  #content {
    width: 100%;
  }

  aside, #title, #menu, .photo img, .asker {
    width: 100%;
  }

}
```

This is why you are having the problem. Find your media query in your CSS and sort it out there. :)